# How to query mongodb in express with or and like operators

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to find the list of airport using autocomplete box. I recently moved from php codeigniter & mysql to node express and mongodb. I am not able to understand how to create this find query in express and mongoose.

here is type of document in mongodb collections

```
{
    "aptid": "2",
    "code": "BJY",
    "name": "Batajnica Airport",
    "cityCode": "BEG",
    "cityName": "Belgrade",
    "countryName": "SERBIA",
    "countryCode": "RS",
    "continent_id": "1",
    "timezone": "1",
    "lat": "44.9236",
    "lon": "20.279",
    "city": "false"
},
{
    "aptid": "3",
    "code": "BJZ",
    "name": "Talaveral La Real Airport",
    "cityCode": "BJZ",
    "cityName": "Badajoz",
    "countryName": "SPAIN",
    "countryCode": "ES",
    "continent_id": "1",
    "timezone": "1",
    "lat": "38.89125",
    "lon": "-6.821333",
    "city": "true"
},
{
    "aptid": "4",
    "code": "BKB",
    "name": "Bikaner Airport",
    "cityCode": "BKB",
    "cityName": "Bikaner",
    "countryName": "INDIA",
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "continent_id": null,
    "timezone": "5",
    "lat": "0",
    "lon": "0",
    "city": "true"
},
 ..... and so on 8000+ data
```

this is the model schema **airports.model.js**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { toJSON, paginate } = require('./plugins');
const airportsSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        aptid: {type: String},
        code: {type: String},
        name: {type: String},
        cityCode: {type: String},
        cityName: {type: String},
        countryName: {type: String},
        countryCode: {type: String},
        continent_id: {type: String},
        timezone: {type: String},
        lat: {type: String},
        lon: {type: String},
        city: {type: String}
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
); 

// add plugin that converts mongoose to json
airportsSchema.plugin(toJSON);
airportsSchema.plugin(paginate);


/**
 * @typedef Airports
 */
const Airports = mongoose.model('Airports', airportsSchema);

module.exports = Airports;
```

this is route **airports.route.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
const airportcontroller = require('../../controllers/airport.controller');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/find', airportcontroller.findAirport);

module.exports = router;
```

here is the controller where I want to build query **airport.controller.js**

```
    const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
const axios = require('axios');
const { Airports } = require('../models');

const findAirport = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {

  try{

       const listairports = await Airports.find(req.body.aptsearchkey).exec();
       //here I need help in creating query
       res.json(listairports);

    }catch(err){

       return res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message
        
      })
    }   
  
});

module.exports ={
    addAirport,
    findAirport
}
```

But I want to create query in above controller, something like this, I had earlier in php codeigniter application

```
     function get_airports($querystring){
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->like('code', $querystring);
     $this->db->or_like('name', $querystring);
     $this->db->or_like('cityCode', $querystring);
     $this->db->or_like('cityName', $querystring);
     $this->db->or_like('countryName', $querystring);
     $result = $this->db->get('pt_flights_airports')->result_array();
     return $result;
   }
```

from @sachin's reference, I did this, but I need to make all queries in case insensitive format. it should not matter, whether provided search string is in uppercase or lowercase.

how to solve that here.

```
    const findAirport = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {

  try{

       const aptsearchkey = req.body.aptsearchkey
       const listairports = await Airports.find({ 
         $or: [ 
            { code: { $regex: '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' } },
            { price: { $regex: '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' } },
            { cityCode: { $regex: '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' } },
            { cityName: { $regex: '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' } },
            { countryName: { $regex: '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' } },
          ] 
        }).exec();
       res.json(listairports);

    }catch(err){

       return res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message

      })
    }   
  
});
```

here how I solved it.

```
    const findAirport = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {

  try{

       const aptsearchkey = req.body.aptsearchkey
       const listairports = await Airports.find({ 
         $or: [ 
            { code: { '$regex': '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' ,$options:'i' } },
            { price: { '$regex': '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' ,$options:'i'} },
            { cityCode: { '$regex': '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' ,$options:'i'} },
            { cityName: { '$regex': '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' ,$options:'i'} },
            { countryName: { '$regex': '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' ,$options:'i'} },
          ] 
        }).exec();
       res.json(listairports);

    }catch(err){

       return res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message

      })
    }   
  
});
```

Comment: refer [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar I followed this and updated my code to work, it is working but I need another help in making query not case-sensitive. can you help me here. it should not matter whether string in which format, it should return result.

Comment: use $regex and add a cas-insensitive regex refer [here](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/schema-suggestions/case-insensitive-regex/)

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar thanks for the suggestion, I solved it, and I updated working code in question.

Answer (score 1):

```
const findAirport = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    
      try{
    
           const aptsearchkey = req.body.aptsearchkey
           const listairports = await Airports.find({ 
             $or: [ 
                { code: { '$regex': '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' ,$options:'i' } },
                { price: { '$regex': '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' ,$options:'i'} },
                { cityCode: { '$regex': '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' ,$options:'i'} },
                { cityName: { '$regex': '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' ,$options:'i'} },
                { countryName: { '$regex': '.*' + aptsearchkey + '.*' ,$options:'i'} },
              ] 
            }).exec();
           res.json(listairports);
    
        }catch(err){
    
           return res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message
    
          })
        }   
      
    });
```

This is how I solved the problem.